# IIS7.X remove directory from being compressed with gzip

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gzip, iis-7.5, http-compression

I am trying to remove one directory from being gziped as it causes errors on the browser.

Here is the code I have. I've read that I can't disable one page only, but there is a way to disable a directory path. I don't have access to server settings, but maybe I could do it from web.config settins by removing or adding a path to staticTypes?

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

Please advice